# Give me a web.config sample code for only emitted JSON in web service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

I want a sample web.config code to result only JSON format when using web service in asp.net.

I used web service asp.net 3.5 and my code is here :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        string json = "hello world";
        return json;
    }
```

and then my output is  here:

```
<string>hello world</string>
```

The problem is that I want to be my output in JSON format ,now is XML .I know I need to edit web.config file but I don't know exactly.Therefore give me a sample web.config file to result JSON format.

Comment: I also want a lot, but I'm very in different asking for.

Comment: I'll give you a close vote. At least read the FAQ for the correct question structure.

Comment: @JamieKeeling I edited my question .If you have a sample file ,let me see .It will be help for me.Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need web.config sample file for asmx web service to result JSON purely.
I got a solution. Anyway thank you all.
If someone want to know more about this ,visit [asmx web service can result JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132604/asmx-web-service-can-result-json-purely)